# Apex Trigger to Update Contact from Custom Object

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex-code

Long story short, I need to update a custom field in my standard Contact, that fires after a different, unrelated Custom Object is updated. I've tried to write a trigger that passes the field value from my Custom Object to the Contact, but I keep getting a variety of errors - the most recent of which has stumped me. The end goal is to update `Passing__c` from `Passing_Field__c`.

I'm getting an `unexpected Token: "("` error on the `for(Contact C:` line. It is literally so simple I cannot figure it out.

Here is my code below. I've simplified the naming convention to try and make it more relatable. Any help is appreciated. I'm pretty new to Apex and Triggers, and I've been at this for a couple of hours now, hopefully some advice can send me to 'home plate'.

```
trigger ContactUpdater on Custom_Object_Name__c (after update) {

     List<Contact> updatedContacts = new List<Contact>();
     Set<Id> ObjectIds = new Set<Id>();
     Set<String> ObjectCont = new Set<String>();
     Set<Boolean> ObjectActive = new Set<Boolean>();
     Set<String> ObjectPass = new Set<String>(); 

     for(Custom_Object_Name__c p : trigger.new)
        {
            If(p.Active__c == true){ 
              ObjectIds.add(p.Id);
              ObjectCont.add(p.Contact__c);
              ObjectActive.add(p.Active__c);
              ObjectPass.add(p.Passing_Field__c);
              }

        try{ for(Contact c : [SELECT Id, Passing__c FROM Contact WHERE (AccountId IN (Select Account__c from  Custom_Object_Name__c )) AND ObjectActive = true])
              {
                 set(c.Passing__c = p.Passing_Field__c);
                 c.FieldToUpdate = c.Passing__c;
                 updatedContacts.add(c);
              }
             update updatedContacts; 

           }

            catch(exception e){
               throw e;
              }
        }
}
```

*Notes: Active__c is a checkbox. Passing__c and Passing_Field__c are both text boxes.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is in the WHERE clause of your SOQL query:

```
WHERE (AccountId = (Select Account__c from Custom_Object_Name__c ))
```

Salesforce is expecting you to compare `AccountId` to an Id of some sort, rather than the results of some subquery. You probably want to try something like:

```
WHERE (AccountId in (Select Account__c from  Custom_Object_Name__c))
```

Comment: I've updated the code above to reflect my current version. The 'IN' operator in place of '=' fixed that bug, but it seems I have a more fundamental one. Its not recognizing `p.Passing_Field__c' as a variable, which leads me to believe I am not referencing the Custom_Object_Name__c correctly. The Contact 'Selects' are OK from what I can tell, but its all for none if the Custom Object isnt getting called correctly. Any ideas? I'll try to rework how I set it up.

Comment: The syntax indentation is through me a bit but your p variable is only valid within in the context of the for loop. outside of that for loop the p variable is not in scope and so that is probably the reason you are getting an error.

Comment: Interesting. I changed the {} brackets around to include the TRY within the  `for(Custom_Object_Name__c p : trigger.new)`. However, I've declared `ObjectPass` as a String, and I've added `Passing_Field__c` to the string. When I get to  `set(c.Passing__c = p.Passing_Field__c);`, I'm getting an "Illegal Assignment from SET<string> to String". It seems as though you cannot just overwrite a string's value with a field value, like I am trying to do. Is there a better way to bring `Passing_Field__c` into the trigger, without using a string?